# TypeScript interface implementations

Tags: interface, typescript

I'm writing a program using `TypeScript`. The problem is I implemented `HTMLElement` interface.

```
export class IEElement implements HTMLElement {
   // something here
}
```

The compiler shows many errors that I have some properties missing (`IEElement` declares an interface but does not implement it). I have implemented about 5 properties that I need to. The rest is redundant. How to avoid errors? Do I need to implement all the interface members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement all non-optional interface members.

The interface is a contract, if you have a class that implements that contract you are promising to implement everything in that contract.

The HTMLElement interface has a lot to implement - but if you just want to add a bit of behaviour, perhaps you could start with an existing implementation...

```
interface SpecialElement extends HTMLElement {
    myCustomFunction: () => void;
}

var element = <SpecialElement>document.getElementById('example');

element.myCustomFunction = function () { };
```

Comment: It's pretty bad:/ Now I have to implement about 70 members... Thanks for the answer. Have a good day.

Comment: @Nickon I've just added a potential solution for you that might make it a bit easier - depending on what you are doing!